# How do I get the values from a dynamically created NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

How to get the values from dynamic `NumericUpDown` in C#?

Here is my code,

```
for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    NumericUpDown notele = new NumericUpDown();
    notele.Name = "note" + i.ToString();              
    notele.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(280, 208 + (30 * i));
    notele.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 25);
    notele.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
    notele.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {10,0,0, 0});
    this.Controls.Add(notele);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access your controls using the [Control collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) of your form and pass to it the name of your `numericUpDown` control:

```
var numericUpDown  = this.Controls["note0"] as NumericUpDown;

if(numericUpDown != null)
{
   var value = numericUpDown.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still utilise the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
...
    notelle.ValueChanged += UpDnValueChangedHandler;

    this.Controls.Add(notele);
}

private void UpDnValueChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender references the control which value was changed:
    NumericUpDown notelle = sender as NumericUpDown;

    // further processing goes here
}
```